# Why GTX-960 cannot Communicate with Matlab 2016a in Windows 10?

Tags: matlab, windows-10, nvidia

System: GTX-960 with NVidia driver 365.10, 32 GB, Lenovo PC 2013, i7 2013, Windows 10 Education edition. 
Test Code in Matlab 2016a based on the CNN manual [here](http://se.mathworks.com/help/nnet/examples/training-a-deep-neural-network-for-digit-classification.html?s_tid=gn_loc_drop)

```
% Load the training data into memory
[xTrainImages, tTrain] = digittrain_dataset;

rng('default'); % random number generator seed

hiddenSize1 = 100; 

autoenc1 = trainAutoencoder(xTrainImages,hiddenSize1, ...
    'MaxEpochs',400, ...
    'L2WeightRegularization',0.004, ...
    'SparsityRegularization',4, ...
    'SparsityProportion',0.15, ...
    'ScaleData', false);

feat1 = encode(autoenc1,xTrainImages);

%% Second set of features
hiddenSize2 = 50;
autoenc2 = trainAutoencoder(feat1,hiddenSize2, ...
    'MaxEpochs',100, ...
    'L2WeightRegularization',0.002, ...
    'SparsityRegularization',4, ...
    'SparsityProportion',0.1, ...
    'ScaleData', false);

feat2 = encode(autoenc2,feat1);

softnet = trainSoftmaxLayer(feat2,tTrain,...
    'MaxEpochs',400, ...
    'useGPU', 'yes',...
    'showResources', 'yes');
softnet.trainFcn = 'trainscg'; % to avoid warning with GPU

view(autoenc2) % The Error comes from here!
```

Output which it gives at the end of the session; otherwise, it seems to optimize correctly but apparently without GPU because *OpenHardwareMonitor* app indicates GPU not in use (GPU Fans 0 RPM, GPU Core Value 0.0-16.0% (changing), Max 68% (not changing)

> Error using trainSoftmaxLayer>iParseInputArguments (line 61) 'useGPU'
>   is not a recognized parameter. For a list of valid name-value pair
>   arguments, see the documentation for this function.

### Hugh's proposal

Changes in code

```
autoenc1 = trainAutoencoder(xTrainImages,hiddenSize1, ...
    'MaxEpochs',400, ...
    'L2WeightRegularization',0.004, ...
    'SparsityRegularization',4, ...
    'SparsityProportion',0.15, ...
    'useGPU', 'yes',...
    'ScaleData', false);

autoenc2 = trainAutoencoder(feat1,hiddenSize2, ...
    'MaxEpochs',100, ...
    'L2WeightRegularization',0.002, ...
    'SparsityRegularization',4, ...
    'SparsityProportion',0.1, ...
    'useGPU', 'yes',...
    'ScaleData', false);

softnet = trainSoftmaxLayer(feat2,tTrain,...
    'MaxEpochs',400, ...
    'showResources', 'yes');
```

Output

```
Error using Autoencoder.parseInputArguments (line 477)
'UseGPU' must be a logical value.

Error in trainAutoencoder (line 103)
paramsStruct  = Autoencoder.parseInputArguments(varargin{:});

Error in bnn_image (line 17)
autoenc1 = trainAutoencoder(xTrainImages,hiddenSize1, ...
```

---

How can you confirm how well GTX-960 communicate with Matlab 2016a in Windows 10?

Comment: "'UseGPU' must be a logical value." Have you tried making `UseGPU` a logical value (such as `true`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trainSoftmaxLayer function does not accept useGPU as an input [(help document on trainSoftmaxLayer)](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/trainsoftmaxlayer.html#namevaluepairarguments) while the trainAutoencoder function does [(help document on trainAutoencoder)](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/trainautoencoder.html#namevaluepairarguments) along with the normal train function [(help document on train)](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/train.html?searchHighlight=usegpu). Can you use either of these functions for your problem? If not and you absolutely need to use Softmax, then you will need to code it yourself - this won't be easy.

Comment: See the body. It seems be the right direction. Now, getting a logical value error.

Comment: As the comments above mention, "'UseGPU' must be a logical value." - use `true` instead of `'yes'`